# getting min and max value from a column in vectors of vector

Tags: c++, vector

I know how to get min and max value in a vector through iterators as shown below, But how about getting a min and max value of a matrix table in vectors of vector: for example i have:

```
vector<vector<float> > vec;
```

the above vector has a matrix (my program reads data from csv file and enters into these vectors of vector as a matrix) , such that i want to check a specific column in the vector of vector and find the min and max values in that particular column, keeping in mind that finding min and max from a specific column of a vector specified.

normal way to find min and max value in a single vector is :

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

    auto biggest = std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::cout << "Max element is " << *biggest
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), biggest) << std::endl;

    auto smallest = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::cout << "min element is " << *smallest
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), smallest) << std::endl;
}
```

but what if the vector has another vector like  `vector<vector<float> > vec;`

Comment: I have thought about a way of doing it but i need a proper answer, for example i can make the row a fix value and then using for loop i can get the value of a column. then store those values in new single vector, then iterate through it to find min and max. but would appreciate if anybody can give me a better solution than creating a new vector.

Comment: I don't think it gets more simple than creating a new vector or array with the desired column.

Comment: there must be a way to iterate through the matrix, like we use iteration to display matrix values, similarly there must be a way of doing it.. i just cant figure it out.. i tried but no luck

Comment: Note that you have `std::minmax_element` instead of calling both `std::max_element` and `std::min_element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second form of [max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and write your own compare functor like this:

```
template< class T >
struct ColumnAdapter {
    ColumnAdapter( size_t column ) : m_column( column ) {}
    bool operator()( const std::vector< T > & left, const std::vector< T > & right ) {
        return left.at( m_column ) < right.at( m_column );
    }
private:
    size_t m_column;
};

int main() {
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > v = {
        { 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
        { 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
        { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 },
        { 2,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
    };
    const size_t COLUMN = 1;
    auto biggest = std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), ColumnAdapter< int >( COLUMN ) );
    std::cout << "Max element is " << (*biggest).at( COLUMN )
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), biggest) << std::endl;

    auto smallest = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), ColumnAdapter< int >( COLUMN ) );
    std::cout << "min element is " << (*smallest).at( COLUMN )
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), smallest) << std::endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> Max element is 30 at position 2
>
> min element is 2 at position 1

[live demo](http://ideone.com/P9D4jo)

Comment: G:\UH\PSE\projects\practise\main.cpp:218:3: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
G:\UH\PSE\projects\practise\main.cpp:218:8: error: 'biggest' does not name a type
G:\UH\PSE\projects\practise\main.cpp:219:41: error: 'biggest' was not declared in this scope
G:\UH\PSE\projects\practise\main.cpp:220:45: error: 'begin' is not a member of 'std'
G:\UH\PSE\projects\practise\main.cpp:222:5: warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]

Comment: all i need to do was to : 
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iomanip>

and then go to the comliler setting and select option g++ follow the c++ ISO

Comment: **First**: I saw `auto` in your code in question and thought that you turned on c++11's features. **Second** I removed includes from answer to make it shorter, but gave you a link to `ideone.com` where you can see that code is realy work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override the the < used with a lambda expression like:

```
size_t col = 1; // tells which column to check
auto comp = [&] (const vector<float> &a, const vector<float> &b)
{
    return a[col] < b[col];
}

//usage

auto max = max_element(mat2d.begin(), mat2d.end(), comp);
float max_val = (*max)[col];
```